# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str Problem with another /nix syntax error

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    insultRange = int(random.randint(0,max(sliceInsults)))
  File "/nix/store/hd4cc9rh83j291r5539hkf6qd8lgiikb-python3-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/random.py", line 370, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

The code in question:

```py
for i in ins:
        sliceInsults = i.split(",")

      amount = int(input("How many insults do you want?"))
      for am in range(0,int(amount)):
        insultRange = int(random.randint(0,max(sliceInsults)))
        print(str(sliceInsults[insultRange]))
```

I was trying to make the range be the max of the list. I've looked everywhere on the internet to find the solution but couldn't find one to fix it.

Comment: Based on the error message you provided, it seems that the max() function is returning a string instead of an integer, and you're trying to concatenate it with an integer using the + operator. This is causing a TypeError.

Comment: `sliceInsults = i.split(",")` would indicate that `sliceInsults` is a list of strings. So, did you mean `len(sliceInsults)`? Because `max(sliceInsults)` returns the maximum value in a list. In this case it's going to return a string of some kind. Probably not what you intended.

Comment: I fixed the type error, but now im getting "list Index out of Range." with this code:  for i in ins:
        sliceInsults = i.split(",")

      amount = int(input("How many insults do you want?"))
      for am in range(0,int(amount)): 
        print((sliceInsults[int(random.randint(0,int(len(sliceInsults))))]))

Comment: Well you'll probably actually need to do `len(sliceInsults) - 1`, since the index is zero-based.

Comment: Use `random.choice()` to pick a random element of a list.

Comment: @TheBrainyCat why are you casting the return value of `len` to an `int`? It is already an `int`, same with `random.randint`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want:

```
# Inputs of beautiful insults
ins = 'good, thebest, pretty, cool, handsome'

# str to list removing white spaces
sliceInsults = []
for i in ins.split(","):
    sliceInsults.append(i.strip())

# Request the amount
amount = int(input("How many insults do you want?"))
if amount.isdecimal():
    amount_int = int(amount)

    # Calculation
    for am in range(0, amount_int):
        insultRange = random.randint(0, len(sliceInsults)-1)
        print(sliceInsults[insultRange])
else:
    print("Invalid input. Please enter an integer.")
```